# Hubot: installing a hubot script

Tags: jenkins, coffeescript, hubot

I installed Hubot with the hipchat adapter. I also installed an external script `hubot-jenkins-enhanced` using `npm`. However, Hubot is not responding to jenkins commands which should listen in this script.

Do I have to manually copy `node_modules/hubot-jenkins-enhanced/index.coffee` to `hubot/scripts`? I can't find any information on how to install a plugin anywhere. I thought that `npm install` would suffice but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to include to the hubot-jenkins script in `external-scripts.json` as described by [the documentation](https://hubot.github.com/docs/):

> To use a script from an NPM package:
>
> 1. Run `npm install --save <package-name>` to add the package as a dependency and install it.
> 2. Add the package to `external-scripts.json`.

Hubot now responds to the jenkins commands.